# How do I get article properties from query in a merge replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I would like to know if there are any queries to get article properties in a SQL Server merge replication. I'm able to get properties only by GUI. I select a publication properties then I get the page properties, then I select an article (a table) then if I want to check the Article Properties, I select Set Properties of Highlighted Table Article I get the four group of properties like as Copy Objects and Settings to Subscriber, Destination Object, Identification and Merging Changes.
Anybody knows if there are any queries to get that properties or to get a script that create the article with of all of these properties?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in [View and Modify Article Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/view-and-modify-article-properties), in the section ***To view the properties of an article belonging to a merge publication***:

> Execute [sp_helpmergearticle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helpmergearticle-transact-sql), specifying the name of the
> publication for the ***@publication*** parameter and the name of the
> article for the ***@article*** parameter. If you do not specify these
> parameters, information will be returned for all articles in a
> publication or at the publisher.

If you want to generate scripts to create replication components, this is covered in [Scripting Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/scripting-replication).

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I already know sp_helpmergearticle. I posted a question here because it's seem to me that what I get Is different from what I can see in the GUI.

Comment: Can you be more specific? As in, what do you see in the results from sp_helpmergearticle vs what do you see in the GUI?

Comment: Yes I do. Here is an example. This is some of all the data that I get from sp_helpmergearticle:
**id                         1
name                 name
source_owner         dbo
source_object         source_object
sync_object_owner dbo
sync_object         MSmerge_DB_VIEW
description 
status                 2**

that doesn't match with the GUI in the Article Properties and the four groups Copy Objects and Settings to Subcriber, Destination Object, Identification and Merging Changes.

Comment: Actually, everything you see from sp_helpmergearticle does in fact match what you see in the GUI. It just might be a little hard to tell what matches to what. Can you give a specific example of a property you seen in the GUI that you do not see in sp_helpmergearticle?

Comment: This is what I get from sp_helpmergearticle: **id 1 name name source_owner dbo source_object source_object sync_object_owner dbo sync_object MSmerge_DB_VIEW description status 2**. It's only a small part of all of the properties get from sp_helpmergearticle because the limit of the size of the comment.
I give you just an example, of what I see in the GUI of the 
Publication Properties, Article Properties: **Copy Objects and Settings to Subscriber**, Copy primary key constraint: **True**.
This property to what matches to the property/column in the sp_helpmergearticle?

Comment: Copy primary key constraint from the GUI corresponds to the schema_option from sp_helpmergearticle. The schema_option is a bitmap of the schema generation option for an article. It's a product of one or more schema_option values covered in sp_addmergearticle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addmergearticle-transact-sql. 0x80 is the value that corresponds to Copy primary key constraint in the GUI and can checked if set using a & (Bitwise AND).

Comment: See the section To change schema options for an existing article in a merge publication here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/specify-schema-options.